# How to Isolate multiple innertext entries when using get elementbyID

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to isolate 2 different `innerText` strings from a webpage, but cannot single them out. The `innerText` for all the tags comes as a whole.
The date and season number are the issue.

I am using `getElementById` and this gives me a single element. The `div` with `id` "next_episode" has what looks like 2 different entries for inner text that I'm interested in. When I loop through the inner text of its children, these 2 entries are skipped. I can't figure out how to isolate the 2 different `innerText` entries of just the "next_episode" tag. I'm isolating the text I require by using the index number in the arrays my code returns.

```
Dim IE_00 As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc_00 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set IE_00 = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE_00.Visible = True

IE_00.navigate "https://next-episode.net/final-space"
Do While IE_00.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
Set HTMLDoc_00 = IE_00.document

Dim NETC_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim NET_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

'Can loop through the inner text of the children one by one and find what 
I need

Set NETC_05 = HTMLDoc_00.getElementById("next_episode").Children

For Each NET_05 In NETC_05
Debug.Print NET_05.innerText
Next NET_05

'This just gives a big block of text that includes the missing inner text 
I need

Set NET_05 = HTMLDoc_00.getElementById("next_episode")
Debug.Print NET_05.innerText
```

Comment: what is the exact info you wish to retrieve please?

Comment: I would like to retrieve the following and place int specific cells; the show status, next episode name, next episode countdown, next episode date, next episode season and next episode number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Setting XML 05 as an Object
    Dim XML_05 As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
'Setting HTML Document 05 as an Object
    Dim HTML_05 As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    XML_05.Open "GET", Cells(Row, NextEpisodeURL).Value, False
    XML_05.send
    HTML_05.body.innerHTML = XML_05.responseText

'Setting Net Element Tag Collection 05 as an Object
    Dim NETC_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
'Setting Net Element Tag 05 as an Object
    Dim NET_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
'Setting Reg EX 05 as an Object
    Dim REO_05 As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
'Setting Match Object 05 as Object
    Dim MO_05 As Object
'Setting Season array as Array
    Dim SN_05() As String
'Setting Episode Name 05 as Array
    Dim ENA_05() As String
'Setting Episode Number 05 as Array
    Dim EN_05() As String

'Getting Episode Name Episode Number and Season Number From Net

'Set NETC_05 = HTML_05.getElementsByClassName("sub_main")
    Set NET_05 = HTML_05.getElementById("previous_episode")
    Set REO_05 = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
        REO_05.Global = True
        REO_05.IgnoreCase = True

'Getting Episode Name
    REO_05.Pattern = "(Name:(.*))"
        Set MO_05 = REO_05.Execute(NET_05.innerText)
            Debug.Print MO_05.Count
            Debug.Print MO_05(0).Value
                ENA_05 = Split(MO_05(0), ":")
            Debug.Print ENA_05(1)
            Cells(Row, NextEpName).Value = ENA_05(1)
    
'Getting Episode Number
    REO_05.Pattern = "(Episode:([0-9]*))"
        Set MO_05 = REO_05.Execute(NET_05.innerText)
            Debug.Print MO_05.Count
            Debug.Print MO_05(0).Value
                EN_05 = Split(MO_05(0), ":")
            Debug.Print EN_05(1)
            Cells(Row, EpisodeNet).Value = EN_05(1)
    
'Getting Season Number
    REO_05.Pattern = "(Season:([0-9]*))"
        Set MO_05 = REO_05.Execute(NET_05.innerText)
            Debug.Print MO_05.Count
            Debug.Print MO_05(0).Value
                SN_05 = Split(MO_05(0), ":")
            Debug.Print SN_05(1)
            Cells(Row, SeasonNet).Value = SN_05(1)
    
'Getting Countdown From Net
    Set NETC_05 = HTML_05.getElementById("next_episode").Children
        Cells(Row, Countdown).Value = NETC_05(5).innerText
        Debug.Print NETC_05(5).innerText
```

```
Public Sub GetShowInfo()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, headers(), i As Long, aCollection As Object, info As Object

    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("Msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "https://next-episode.net/chicago-fire", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set aCollection = html.getElementById("next_episode").getElementsByTagName("div")
    Set aCollection = html.getElementById("next_episode").getElementsByClassName("subheadline")
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each ele In aCollection
            Debug.Print ele.innerText
            Debug.Print ele.outerText
            Debug.Print ele.nextElementSibling.innerText
            Debug.Print ele.nextElementSibling.innerText
        Next ele
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Data (for the most part) is in `NextSiblings`:

[image]

> The Node.nextSibling read-only property returns the node immediately
>   following the specified one in their parent's childNodes, or returns
>   null if the specified node is the last child in the parent element.
>   <sub>*1</sub>

---

You could write a function, like `GetNextSiblings`,  which checks the current node for specific search strings and then extracts required values from `NextSibling`. I have re-ordered output columns to make for less code, but you could easily loop an alternative headers array, and use that ordering to access from dict `info` to write out values in a different order. I determine order of output by order of entry of keys in the dict. I loop the headers array to populate the dict keys and later update the dict with the values scraped.

The overhead of a browser is not needed as the required content is not dynamically loaded. A simple, and much faster, [xhr](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) request will suffice.

---

**Side-note:**

I would recommend, for this type of page, to use Python 3 and BeautifulSoup (bs4 4.7.1+) as this gives you access to pseudo selector `:contains`. The code could then be much more concise and the program faster. I show this at the end.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetShowInfo()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, headers(), i As Long, aCollection As Object, info As Object

    headers = Array("Name:", "Countdown:", "Date:", "Season:", "Episode:", "Status:")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("Msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "https://next-episode.net/final-space", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set info = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        info(headers(i)) = vbNullString
    Next

    info("Name:") = html.querySelector("#next_episode .sub_main").innerText
    info("Countdown:") = html.querySelector("#next_episode span").innerText
    Set aCollection = html.getElementById("middle_section").getElementsByTagName("div")
    Set info = GetNextSiblings(aCollection, headers, info)
    Set aCollection = html.getElementById("next_episode").getElementsByTagName("div")
    Set info = GetNextSiblings(aCollection, headers, info)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, info.Count) = info.keys
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, info.Count) = info.items
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetNextSiblings(ByVal aCollection As Object, ByRef headers(), ByVal info As Object) As Object
    Dim item As Object, i As Long
    For Each item In aCollection
        For i = 2 To UBound(headers)
            If InStr(item.outerHTML, headers(i)) > 0 Then
                If headers(i) = "Episode:" Then
                    info(headers(i)) = item.NextSibling.innerText
                Else
                    info(headers(i)) = item.NextSibling.NodeValue
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Set GetNextSiblings = info
End Function
```

---

**Reading:**

1. [NextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)
2. [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
3. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

---

**Python (with bs4 4.7.1+):**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://next-episode.net/final-space')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')    
current_nodes = ['Status:','Name:', 'Countdown:','Date:','Season:','Episode:']

for node in current_nodes:
    selector = f'#middle_section div:contains("{node}"), #next_episode div:contains("{node}")'
    if node in ['Episode:','Name:']:
        print(node, soup.select_one(selector).text.replace(node,''))
    elif node == 'Countdown:':
         print(node, soup.select_one(selector).next_sibling.text)
    else:
        print(node, soup.select_one(selector).next_sibling)
```

Comment: Any questions about this?

Comment: Yeah the majority of that is above my head. I'm going to do all the recommended reading and break down the code you gave me. Might take a while. I did manage to find a solution by grinding the techniques I already know. I'll post it for reference.  I have a feeling my entire project has alot of overhead.

Comment: Sure thing. Come back with any questions at anytime ;-)

Comment: I posted an answer Qharr. Don't thunk it would have fit in the comment

Comment: cool.... you should post the entire code of your answer so others can use it in future. Also, indent your code properly to make it easier for people to read.

Comment: Yeah that was the other thing I was going to ask about. Im not sure about code indentation. Just been winging it

Comment: you can potentially install a tool like [Rubbderduck VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/) - It has the ability to indent your code, inspect it and make suggestions and so much more.

Comment: Hi QHarr, Ive been streamlining my project but have hit a brick wall with what you helped me with last time. Having trouble finding the correct elements to reference  as the site changed.

Comment: Hi QHarr, Ive been looking over this old answer from a few years ago and am having trouble with your code. I believe the website has changed and isnt replying with the data I need. The part I do have working returns everything I require except 2 values. Just wondering if you can see what im doing wrong.
Ill post the code in the comments